# -Webkit-Backdrop-Filter Ignore the Border Radius Property

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I tried to make an html to image, but I found that the -webkit-backdrop-filter will ignore the border-radius property if I run the code on my iPhone 13(ios 16)

**As you can see from the photo,the left one is the normal on computer and the right is on iPhone without border-radius property display**
[image]

Below is my code

```
var styleTag = document.createElement("style");
var cssRules = "h1{\n" + 
                "font-family: Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;\n" +
               "}\n" +
               ".card-container {\n" +
               "  position: relative;\n" +
               "  width: 300px;\n" +
               "  height: 400px;\n" +
               "  border-radius: 15px;\n" +
               "  overflow: hidden;\n" +
            
               "}\n" +
               ".album-cover {\n" +
               "background-image: url('https://images.pexels.com/photos/949587/pexels-photo-949587.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&w=200&h=200&dpr=2');\n"  +
               "  width: 100%;\n" +
               "  height: 100%;\n" +
              "}\n" +
               ".blur-overlay {\n" +
               "  position: absolute;\n" +
               "  top: 0;\n" +
               "  left: 0;\n" +
               "  width: 100%;\n" +
               "  height: 100%;\n" +
               "  backdrop-filter: blur(10px);\n" +
               "  -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(10px);\n"+
    //           "  border-radius: 12px;\n" + 
          //     "border: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.125);\n" +
               
               "}\n" +
               ".lyrics {\n" +
               "  position: absolute;\n" +
               "  top: 50%;\n" +
               "  left: 50%;\n" +
               "  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);\n" +
               "  text-align: center;\n" +
               "  padding: 20px;\n" +
               "  color: white;\n" +
               "}\n" +
               ".song-info {\n" +
               "  position: absolute;\n" +
               "  bottom: 0;\n" +
               "  left: 0;\n" +
               "  width: 100%;\n" +
               "  padding: 10px;\n" +
               "  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);\n" +
               "  color: white;\n" +
              

               "}";
styleTag.innerHTML = cssRules;
document.head.appendChild(styleTag);

// 创建 card-container 和其内部元素
var cardContainer = document.createElement("div");
cardContainer.className = "card-container";

var albumCover = document.createElement("div");
albumCover.className = "album-cover";

var blurOverlay = document.createElement("div");
blurOverlay.className = "blur-overlay";

var lyrics = document.createElement("div");
lyrics.className = "lyrics";
lyrics.innerHTML = "笔记";

var songInfo = document.createElement("div");
songInfo.className = "song-info";
songInfo.innerHTML = "<p>歌曲名称</p><p>作者</p>";

// 将内部元素添加到 cardContainer 中
cardContainer.appendChild(albumCover);
cardContainer.appendChild(blurOverlay);
cardContainer.appendChild(lyrics);
cardContainer.appendChild(songInfo);

// 将 cardContainer 添加到 <body> 标签中
document.body.appendChild(cardContainer);

// 添加<h1>元素到<body>标签中
var h1 = document.createElement("h1");
h1.textContent = "文本";

document.body.appendChild(h1);

// 创建一个<div>元素用于显示截图，并添加到<body>标签中
var screenshotDiv = document.createElement("div");
screenshotDiv.id = "screenshot";
document.body.appendChild(screenshotDiv);
```

I test it with **remove -webkit-backdrop-filter and the border-radius back** on my phone, but I cannot remove it, because **the blur effects will go with removing -webkit-backdrop-filter**

So, what should I do if I want to keep both blur effect and border-radius effect?

Thanks

Comment: `Below is my code` - twice? both times without any HTML

Comment: @JaromandaX I thought it was provided by stackoverflow automatically  the first one is a stackoverflow run code tool, it can run my code if you click "run code snippet" button and you will see the result without needing html code, You can open it on win computer and iPhone, so you will see the different result. The second code is what I really write, it is a JavaScript, not html

Comment: @JaromandaX Thanks for your hints, I have removed  the code snippet